# How can I take affect on app while changed the react native source code?

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native

I edit the react native source code:

E:\project_name\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\modules\statusbar\StatusBarModule.java

But when I use these command to clean cache and run again, I can't take affect with what I changed.
`npm cache clean
npm start -- --reset-cache
react-native start
react-native run-android`

I also clean these cache "C:\Users\My_Name.gradle\caches" and run these commands again, but nothing happened.

How can I rebuild the app to apply these changes?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build React Native from source if you want to modify the react native core code.

This [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/android-building-from-source.html) has the steps to build react native from source code.